# how to assign a char to an variable on the base of the size of an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, list, if-statement, arraylist, char

I try to make an long if-statement more compact; this is how it is originaly:

```
char x;
if(list.size()== 1){
    x = 'a';
}
if(list.size()== 2){
    x = 'b';
}
if(list.size() == 3){
    x = 'c';
}
if(list.size() == 4){
    x= 'd';
}
```

Is there a possibility to compact this code?

thanks already,
Jari Van M

Comment: ``char x = (char)('a' + list.size()-1);``, works for ``a`` to ``z``

Comment: You can make use of switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first step, we refactor the code to an `if`-`else` cascade and backup the list size we are going to use often:

**1:**

```
int size = list.size();
char x;
if(size == 1) {
    x = 'a';
} else if(size == 2) {
    x = 'b';
} else if(size == 3) {
    x = 'c';
} else if(size == 4) {
    x = 'd';
} else {
    //undefined
    x = '\0';
}
```

As we compare the list size with constants only in this case, we can further transform this into a `switch` statement:

**2:**

```
char x;
switch (list.size()) {
    case 1: x = 'a'; break;
    case 2: x = 'b'; break;
    case 3: x = 'c'; break;
    case 4: x = 'd'; break;
    //undefined
    default: x = '\0'; break;
}
```

Assuming this isn't a randomly chosen example but real code, we see that we need a function which takes a number starting from `1` which outputs the alphabet (`'a'` to `'z'`) with increasing value:

**3:**

```
char x;
if(list.isEmpty()) {
    //undefined
    x = '\0';
} else {
    //our function
    x = (char) ('a' + list.size() - 1);
    if(x > 'z') {
        //undefined
        x = '\0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easier Option:**
Use `switch case`.

**Tricker Option:**

```
char x = (char) ('a' + list.size() - 1);
```

Comment: missing ``(char)`` cast here

Comment: I don't think you need a cast since you are assigning it to a char anyway.

Comment: The ``+`` operator for ``char`` results in an ``int``. You *must* cast that to ``char`` or it won't compile.

Comment: Using ``javac`` at version ``1.8_u45`` doesn't work.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman, you are right... when I use `char x = 'a' + 1 - 1;` it works fine.. But when I use `char x = 'a' + list.size() -1;` it doesn't... Strange... Updated my answer though...

Answer (score 0):

**You are basically mapping the size to a character**. It can be done easier:

```
x = 'a' + list.size() - 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
char x;
int size = list.size();
if (size >= 1 && size <= 4) {
    x = "zabcd".charAt(size); 
}
```

Comment: @enkor Yes it _does_ provide an answer to the question.  The question is how to write code, equivalent to that given, but more compactly.  How is this not an answer?

Comment: Ok, yes technically it answers the question.  Obviously I was not precise in my comment and apologise.  
It would help however to provide an explanation of the code, it does not explain what your code does.  Ok, fair enough people should be bright enough to pick there way through it and figure out what it is doing.  But I believe this is not in the spirit of stackoverflow.